# sender and instance arguments of post_save signal in Django

Tags: django

I'm confused with [Django's post-save signal documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save):

> sender
> The model class.
>
> instance
> The actual instance being saved.

Is "sender" the class of the model instance *being saved*? Is "instance" an instance *of the sender model* ? i.e. if I registered a signal receiver to receive post_save signals from the User model using signal.connect(), would "sender" be the User model and "instance" be the instance of the User model being saved ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you said, and [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) is a good tutorial for `signals` instead of Django docs